Issue connecting Codebuild to RDS (Sequelize command)
I'm getting the following error in Codebuild when trying to connect to local RDS instance.
Tried adding inbound rules to RDS for all Codebuild IPs listed in AWS from the documentation below and no dice.
https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json
`Config file generated at: /codebuild/output/src712865945/src/config/config.json
Sequelize CLI [Node: 20.18.1, CLI: 6.6.2, ORM: 6.37.5]
Loaded configuration file "config/config.json".
Using environment "test".
ERROR: connect ETIMEDOUT XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5432
[Container] 2024/12/22 11:50:51.633398 Command did not exit successfully npm run seed exit status 1
[Container] 2024/12/22 11:50:51.639730 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2024/12/22 11:50:51.639747 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: npm run seed. Reason: exit status 1`
Tried changing VPC details to match all resources
Adding Codebuild IP details to SG
